# Is there an AllJoyn SDK for c# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, service, server, alljoyn

Is there an AllJoyn SDK for C# / .NET ?
- I want to create an AllJoyn Service in a console application, which have to run on my Windows Server and I only could find the AllJoyn SDK for Windows Universal Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started one here: https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynDotNet

More or less all of the C API is exposed to C#, but the nicer easier-to-work-with helper classes around it is still a work in progress (but feel free to chip in!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a C# desktop application, as a console app implies, there is NOT one currently. The AllJoyn api coverage in the Win10 universal library is so small as to be worthless for anything but C++ UWP apps so your only option is p/invoke and it is rather tedious. The old version of AllJoyn (14.x) had a C# .Net wrapper but it was removed as it was apparently not maintained. The code can be found in the AllSeen Alliance git repositories but updating it for the newer apis will be tedious.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is there...at least for Win10 Universal (and IOT)
In VS2015 you have project templates as well as you  can use "AllJoyn Explorer" (can be found in the link below)
Check it out here
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AllJoyn.htm